# Does the refusal of a visitor visa for Canada affect our UK skilled worker visa application?

Tags: uk, canada, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I applied for a visitor visa for Canada through an agent. I don’t know the reason the agent listed for the visitor visa in the application.

The visa was refused but I didn't receive a reason for refusal; there's no stamp in my passport. My agent now doesn't answer my calls.

If I disclose this refusal in my UK skilled worker visa application, will it affect my UK visa? What reason should I provide in the UK visa application form?

Comment: Did you get a letter of refusal from Canadian immigration?

Comment: @DJClayworth: this question is important, because the behaviour of the agent indicates that the OP might have been the victim of a scam. It could even be that no application was ever submitted to Canadian authorities.

Comment: Normally a visitor visa would be refused if they believe that you want to stay permanently, illegally. A skilled worker visa means you want to stay permanently, legally. So this shouldn’t affect the second application.

Answer (score 20):

Visitor visa rejection is usually not a big problem. Settlement visa is independently assessed, as the premise is different. Being denied a visitor visa before is therefore not a big deal and won't usually hurt your chances. So, you should disclose any visa rejections before.

*"if will disclose this"*

Being said that, if you don't disclose your rejection, its is sure that you **won't get your visa** and **you will be likely banned** from UK for a definite time, due to the act of **deception**. You should disclose even if you are not sure why it is rejected. There is field to add extra information to elaborate on the circumstances.

[And yes, UK and Canada shares immigration information.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Migration_5)

Answer (score 15):

If your agent was not a Canadian lawyer or a regulated immigration consultant, they were not legally authorized under Canadian law to provide advice or direct your application for payment.

In the unlikely case that they are regulated, they must give you information and all correspondences to and from the government upon request. You may complain either to the bar association of their province (for lawyers) or the [College of Immigration and Citizenship Consultants](https://college-ic.ca/protecting-the-public/complaints-process/make-a-complaint).

Unfortunately, in many cases, you cannot be even sure that they submitted your application to the Canadian government.

If you have doubts regarding the handling of your Canadian visa application by your agent, you can request a copy of your files and correspondances under [the Access to Information Act](https://atip-aiprp.apps.gc.ca/atip/welcome.do) from Immigration, Refugees and Citizenship Canada (IRCC, Department of Citizenship and Immigration). To file such a request, you will need the help of a Canadian friend or someone physically located in Canada. The government usually responds within two months (despite the 30-day legal deadline).